# Read incoming sms at every time in Oreo

Tags: android

I want to read all sms messages from specific number at any time not relating when app is runned or not runned. How can I read all messages when app is not runned, in newer versions of android?

Comment: i think broadcast receiver will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a broadcast receiver for this as suggested by @abdul.

1-Add the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

2-Create a BroadCastreceiver Class

Don't forget to properly handle the permissions on Android 6.0 and above.

You should also probably set a high `android:priority` for broadcast receiver intent filter.

**Important:** Please note that this is a very unstable functionality which is not garanteed to work on every Android phone and will largely depend on the system and installed apps.

Comment: Is it working after phone rebooted?

Comment: @Benfactor for this you need to create a separate broadcast receiver to listen for `BOOT_COMPLETED` event to start the sms broadcast receiver. Please note that this would need the respective permission as well. The example tutorial https://riptutorial.com/android/example/15019/broadcastreceiver-to-handle-boot-completed-events